# Angular test - Mock for a image url - return a different url instead of original

Tags: angular, mocking, karma-jasmine, angular-test, karma-webpack

In my angular Application , I have a page where i load bunch of images.

All those images comes from a library. So when ever I run my spec test I get an error

```
404: /_karmawebpack_//assets/images/my_image.svg
```

We use karma-jasmine for testing and our library is packaged using karma-webpack.

The scope is only spec test - I can ignore the images being rendered in spec test.

Is there a way I can mock all such url  and return a dummy url instead of that, as per shown below

```
/_karmawebpack_//assets/images/* -->    .//favicon.ico
```

I tried few things using router - but it didn't help much

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone

After trying out multiple combination below karma config change worked for me

It needs to find the path of the resources in the component - so a proxy config will be needed for it

```
proxies: {
"//asset/images" : "node_modules/@my_module/asset/images/"
}
```

so the paths here are

```
 **//asset/images**  - is the path where i am exporting the images in my component
 
 **node_modules/@my_module/asset/images/** - is the path in current project where i see images under the node_module
```

After adding this - it did not complain about missing images .